# painting a dot at click

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

Hello I want to know how to get the position of the mouse outside the method MouseClicked
this I need for drawing a dot at the place where someone clicks.. this is the code that I use now. Can someone help me with this?

```
    Dot punt = new Dot();

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    punt.setDot(g, getX(), getY(), 5);

    repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    gebeurtenisverslag.setText( 
            m.getClickCount() + " keer geklikt op " + m.getX() + "," + m.getY());
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a variable for the class that mouseClicked modifies.

```
private int X;
private int Y;

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m) {
    gebeurtenisverslag.setText( 
            m.getClickCount() + " keer geklikt op " + m.getX() + "," + m.getY());
    X = m.getX();
    Y = m.getY();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //Probably want to add logic here to verify X & Y have been set
    punt.setDot(g, X, Y, 5);
    repaint();
}
```